# Salesforce Mobile SDK Setting shouldAuthenticate to false returns exception

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

Version of Mobile SDK Used: 5.1.0
Hybrid remote app

Create project with usual steps and in bootconfig.json, set shouldAuthenticate to false and startPage is a public page in Salesforce community:

```
{ "remoteAccessConsumerKey": "xxxxxx", 
      "oauthRedirectURI": "xxxx://auth/success", 
      "oauthScopes": ["web", "api"], 
      "isLocal": false, 
      "startPage": "/acmemoblanding", 
      "errorPage": "error.html", 
      "shouldAuthenticate": false, 
      "attemptOfflineLoad": false
}
```

Start simulator in Xcode, exception is returned (see below). The app start page is never displayed.

Setting shouldAuthenticate to true works but this is not how i want my app to behave.

I believe this is what you do to set up a app that does not require logging in. Is there anything that's missing ?

objc[2228]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x114e68998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x114c8dd38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. 2017-09-18 12:43:23.626 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/mobiledevelopment/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A3D38A77-D405-4AEA-B262-72EE2402F3DC/data/Containers/Data/Application/5A107B1E-C3C7-4C42-979C-461D6E70A593/Library/Cookies/au.com.acme.acmemobile.binarycookies 2017-09-18 12:43:23.750611 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] Launching the Salesforce SDK. 2017/09/18 02:43:23.751 acmeMobileiOS[2228:4713] INFO com.salesforce : Launching the Salesforce SDK. 2017-09-18 12:43:23.755259 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] SDK Manager is configured not to attempt authentication at launch. Skipping auth. 2017/09/18 02:43:23.756 acmeMobileiOS[2228:1e07] INFO com.salesforce : SDK Manager is configured not to attempt authentication at launch. Skipping auth. 2017-09-18 12:43:23.768793 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] Post-launch: launch actions taken: SFSDKLaunchActionAuthBypassed 2017/09/18 02:43:23.769 acmeMobileiOS[2228:1e07] INFO com.salesforce : Post-launch: launch actions taken: SFSDKLaunchActionAuthBypassed 2017-09-18 12:43:23.770 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.0 is starting. 2017-09-18 12:43:23.772 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES 2017-09-18 12:43:23.789113 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] addSidCookieForDomain: (null) 2017/09/18 02:43:23.790 acmeMobileiOS[2228:1e07] DEBUG com.salesforce : addSidCookieForDomain: (null) 2017-09-18 12:43:23.808 acmeMobileiOS[2228:63890] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument' *** First throw call stack: ( 0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010760f34b exceptionPreprocess + 171 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010704721e objc_exception_throw + 48 2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107678265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197 3 Foundation 0x000000010463cf29 -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:] + 96 4 Foundation 0x0000000104679768 +[NSString stringWithString:] + 45 5 acmeMobileiOS 0x00000001030dc973 -[SFHybridViewController frontDoorUrlWithReturnUrl:returnUrlIsEncoded:createAbsUrl:] + 1123 6 acmeMobileiOS 0x00000001030dd82d -[SFHybridViewController configureRemoteStartPage] + 93 7 acmeMobileiOS 0x00000001030daa57 -[SFHybridViewController viewDidLoad] + 967 8 UIKit 0x00000001052c6c99 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258 9 UIKit 0x00000001052c70cc -[UIViewController view] + 27 10 UIKit 0x0000000105190c51 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71 11 UIKit 0x0000000105191c62 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 421 12 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102e4aa58 -[AppDelegate(SalesforceHybridSDK) setupRootViewController] + 312 13 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102e494df __55-[AppDelegate(SalesforceHybridSDK) sfsdk_swizzled_init]_block_invoke + 175 14 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102f9e989 -[SalesforceSDKManager sendPostLaunch] + 116 15 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102f9f9fc -[SalesforceSDKManager authValidationAtLaunch] + 244 16 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102f9de72 -[SalesforceSDKManager launch] + 520 17 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102e49b29 -[AppDelegate(SalesforceHybridSDK) sfsdk_swizzled_application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 697 18 UIKit 0x000000010511c0be -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290 19 UIKit 0x000000010511da43 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236 20 UIKit 0x0000000105123de9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731 21 UIKit 0x0000000105120f69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188 22 FrontBoardServices 0x0000000108568723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 24 23 FrontBoardServices 0x000000010856859c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189 24 FrontBoardServices 0x0000000108568925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45 25 CoreFoundation 0x00000001075b4311 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17 26 CoreFoundation 0x000000010759959c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 27 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107598a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918 28 CoreFoundation 0x0000000107598494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 29 UIKit 0x000000010511f7e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434 30 UIKit 0x0000000105125964 UIApplicationMain + 159 31 acmeMobileiOS 0x0000000102e2e7c1 main + 65 32 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000108d9c68d start + 1 33 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)